Why the exchange don’t works
I bought 30 dollars of worth solana, for exchange them but everyone I try to exchange the phantom platform tell me that I don’t have enough solana whether I have more than 0,05 SOL, can somebody help me please? I want to be refunded cause it’s not normal

perhaps you are trying to exchange the whole 30 dollars of SOL to another token without leaving in the tx + token accounts costs.
Try exchanging $25 instead so that you have enough funds to cover the transaction plus token account creation costs
